# How can we solve the following number theory problem?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers less than $2000$ which satisfies the equation $(m^2-mn-n^2)^2=1$. How can we determine the largest possible value of the expression $m^2+n^2$?

Comment: Brute force on a computer. This (maybe) belongs to Math Stack Exchange.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048219

Comment: Why would one want to do this? What's special about $2000$?

Answer (score 7):

This is a variant of [IMO 1981/3](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1981_IMO_Problems/Problem_3) and can be solved by the exact same method.